# Logstash http_poller post giving Name may not be found error

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

Im trying to use the http_poller to fetch the data from ElasticSearch and write them into another ES. While doing this, ES query need to done as a POST request. 
In the examples provided, I could not find the parameters that shoukd be used to post the body and it referred to the manticore client from ruby. Based n that, I have used the params parameter to post the body.

The http_poller component looks like this

```
input {


 http_poller {
    urls => {
      some_other_service => {
        method => "POST"
        url => "http://localhost:9200/index-2016-03-26/_search"
        params => '"query": { "filtered": { "filter": { "bool": { "must": [ { "term":  { "SERVERNAME": "SERVER1" }}, {"range": { "eventtime": { "gte": "26/Mar/2016:13:00:00" }}} ]}}} }"'
      }
    }
    # Maximum amount of time to wait for a request to complete
    request_timeout => 300
    # How far apart requests should be
    interval => 300
    # Decode the results as JSON
    codec => "json"
    # Store metadata about the request in this key
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

When I execute this, the Logstash gives an error, 
 Error: Name may not be null {:level=>:error}

Any help is appreciated.

The guess that I have is that the params need to be really key value pairs but then the question is as to how to post a query using logstash.

I referred to this link to get the available options for the HTTP Client 
https://github.com/cheald/manticore/blob/master/lib/manticore/client.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I got the answer when I tried different options, thought I would share the solution as well.

Replace params with body in the above payload.

The correct payload to do a post using HTTP Poller is

```
input {


 http_poller {
    urls => {
      some_other_service => {
        method => "POST"
        url => "http://localhost:9200/index-2016-03-26/_search"
        body=> '"query": { "filtered": { "filter": { "bool": { "must": [ { "term":  { "SERVERNAME": "SERVER1" }}, {"range": { "eventtime": { "gte": "26/Mar/2016:13:00:00" }}} ]}}} }"'
      }
    }
    # Maximum amount of time to wait for a request to complete
    request_timeout => 300
    # How far apart requests should be
    interval => 300
    # Decode the results as JSON
    codec => "json"
    # Store metadata about the request in this key
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```